# Share Point 2013 news feed and Followed Count web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I had a requirement from my client to have news feed and I'm Following web parts on their home site's landing page. So I exported the 'Followed Count' web part from My Site page to the landing page, and added a Newsfeed web part from Social Collaboration > Newsfeed.

Both the web parts are working fine. Now the client doesn't want the Newsfeed web part, so I deleted the web part. but the 'I'm following' -- exported from My Site -- web part is not working.

My question is: Is there a connection between these two web parts? Does the Newfeed web part have to be present for the 'I'm following' web part to work?

Thanks.